# ImportError when loading Open3D module into Blender python console

Tags: python, import, command-line

I have installed the [Open3D](http://www.open3d.org) module using `pip` into the interpreter of Blender 2.79b, which uses Python 3.5.3. If I open the Python interpreter from the system console everything works fine without any error message after importing the module.

However, if I open the embedded console of Blender and import Open3D I get the following error:

```
>>> import open3d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/blender-2.79b-linux-glibc219-x86_64/2.79/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/open3d/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .open3d import * # py2 py3 compatible
ImportError: std::bad_cast
```

Furthermore, if I include something different before Open3D (eg, numpy) the error changes into this:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> import open3d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/blender-2.79b-linux-glibc219-x86_64/2.79/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/open3d/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .open3d import * # py2 py3 compatible
ImportError: generic_type: cannot initialize type "VerbosityLevel": an object with that name is already defined
```

So far, I've tried Blender 2.79a, 2.79b and 2.80 with different versions of Open3D and numpy, but I'm not able to find a solution. Trying the newer Blender 2.80 (Python 3.7.0) the error changes again into:

```
>>> import open3d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/blender-2.80-linux-glibc217-x86_64/2.80/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/open3d/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .open3d import * # py2 py3 compatible
ImportError: Invalid character class.
```

What could it be?
Thanks.

**Environment**

OS: Ubuntu 18.04, Python version: 3.5.3 / 3.7.0, Open3D version: 0.8.0.0

[Blender 2.79b](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/) is installed in `/opt/blender-2.79b-linux-glibc219-x86_64`.
In order to install the package I ran the following commands:

```
cd /opt/blender-2.79b-linux-glibc219-x86_64
./2.79/python/bin/python3.5m 2.79/python/lib/python3.5/ensurepip
./2.79/python/bin/pip3.5 install open3d
```

Same commands for the 2.80 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several attempts, I found a solution. In order to fix the `ImportError`, install Open3D v0.4.0.0:

```
pip3 install open3d-python==0.4.0.0
```

Note that the package name has changed: use `open3d-python` instead of `open3d`. Probably, the latest versions of Open3D have some bugs (see also [this Open3D issue](https://github.com/intel-isl/Open3D/issues/922)).